# MongoDB query to find out documents with phone numbers which are not in XXX-XXX-XXXX format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in which documents have "phone" string field in XXX-XXX-XXXX this format. but there are some phone numbers in different format so we want to find out that documents which have different phone format. 
MongoDB query to find out documents with phone numbers which are not in XXX-XXX-XXXX format.

Comment: I tried to use regex. I have written Java code to find out whether give string is in xxx-xxx-xxxx format but I want to do it through query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.yourCollection.find({
    phone: {
        $not: /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
    }
})
```

For the following collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f059ea2504d6157d58c579"), 
    "phone" : "123-123-1234"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f059f92504d6157d58c57a"), 
    "phone" : "234-234-2345"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f05a0f2504d6157d58c57b"), 
    "phone" : "11-111-12222"
}
```

It returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f05a0f2504d6157d58c57b"), "phone" : "11-111-12222" }
```

If you want to restrict the phone number more, just tweak the regex pattern.